# Hibernate Envers has problems with UUID type in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have SpringBoot application with SpringData and Hibernate-Envers. The audited Endity looks as follows:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.*

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="MY_RULE"
public class MyRule
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @Basic
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="RULE_NAME"
    private String ruleName;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Schema is created with liquibase. ID type is **VARCHAR(36)**. The same solution only without envers works on both Postgresql and H2 databases.

To get the Envers revisions I call the method **findLastChangeRevision** on Spring-Data repository:

```
@Repository
interface MyRuleRepository extends JpaRepository<MyRule, UUID> {}

UUID id = ...;
myRuleRepository.findLastChangeRevision(id);
```

This call causes however the following error on **Postgresql** (on **H2** works fine):

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = uuid
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 391
```

Any suggestion on possible solution? I think to migrate from UUID to String, but it looks more like workaround and breaks the code.

Comment: Why do you want to use a varchar for a UUID? That's rather inefficient

Comment: Is there any other way which works for both H2 and Postgresql?

Comment: PostgreSQL, H2 and Liquibase all support the UUID data type, that should be no problem. But your code generates some (unknown) SQL that tells the database it's a varchar instead of an uuid. Could you share the SQL and the code that generates this SQL?

Comment: @Frank Heikens  do you know what's the best solution if we use varchar to store uuid and now I want to use envers? why is it inefficient ?